# npm i @capacitor/core after '@capacitor/core@*' is not in this registry. Error

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@capacitor/android/@capacitor%2fcore
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@capacitor/core@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/erensengun/.npm/_logs/2022-03-12T09_04_56_624Z-debug-0.log
erensengun@ERENs-MacBook-Pro ~ % ionic -v
6.18.1
erensengun@ERENs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm init @capacitor/app
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@capacitor/android/@capacitor%2fcreate-app
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@capacitor/create-app@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
Follow this checklist when you are facing a npm ERR! 404 and you can’t fix it:
install latest npm version
login (if you are downloading a private package)
try to install the package
try to delete the .npmrc file from your home directory
re-try to install the package